# Android Studio installation - standalone SDK will not launch; file watcher failed to start

Tags: android, sdk

I am (still) trying to get Android studio installed and am going to try to describe all of the symptoms, hoping that it helps.

I am running Android Studio as administrator (Win 10), with my firewall turned off. The welcome page comes up with the warning that File watcher failed to start.

I click "Check for Updates" and see "Connection failed (dl.google.com)" even though I can use a browser to go to that site.

I open the SDK manager and click on the bottom where it says "Launch Standalone SDK Manager" and nothing happens.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Firewall was disabled, but not entirely.

It was the firewall.  I disabled the firewall, but I failed to disable the Defense+ part which was preventing the processes from being created.  CreateProcess error=5 turned out to be Defense+ blocking the process.